# What is the best way to avoid sending too much data in JSON to a Telerik Grid when using Ajax binding?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, telerik

The software that I'm developing uses ASP.NET MVC and Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC frameworks.

The problem that I have is that it is very easy to send unintended data in JSON format to the client browser, if a Telerik grid uses ajax binding.

For example, the following action, when used with a Telerik Grid view which uses ajax binding, will result in **all of the Client class's properties being serialized to JSON.**

Model class:

```
public class Client
{
    public int ClientId {get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    ...
    public string SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Client> clients = clientRepository.GetClients();
    return View(new GridModel(clients));
}
```

View:

```
@Html.Telerik().Grid<Client>()
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(client => client.ClientId);
        columns.Bound(client => client.Name);
        columns.Bound(client => client.Address);
    }
    .DataBinding(db => db.Ajax().Select("Index"))
```

Even though *SocialSecurityNumber* and *BankAccountNumber* are not bound to the grid, the JSON will contain them, and the data will be viewable with developer tools such as Firebug.

JSON:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "ClientId":101,
         "Name":"Matt",
         "Address":"Example Road 12",
         ...
         "SocialSecurityNumber":"1234-5678"
         "BankAccountNumber":"12345678",
      },
      {
         "ClientId":102,
         "Name":"Karen",
         "Address":"Example Road 27",
         ...
         "SocialSecurityNumber":"5678-1234"
         "BankAccountNumber":"87654321",
      }
   ],
   "total":2
}
```

**What solution would you use to make sure that only the intended properties are serialized and sent to the client browser?**

Comment: I think you will have to filter those in the action method. you create a dynamic object and return the list of dynamic objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a ViewModel that contains the exact properties you want to expose and use that instead of the object you are currently using:

```
public class ClientModel
{
    public int ClientId {get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

var model = from c in clients
            select new ClientModel {
               ...
            };

return View(new GridModel(model));
```

Comment: This is the solution that I used. However, I would name the class "ClientViewModel" in this case to make it perfectly clear that it's a view model class. "Model" is such an overused word. :) But where would you put this class, in the UI project or in a separate domain project? Also which component should do the mapping of Client to Client(View)Model? Should I even be exposing the Client class to the UI project, or only the Client(View)Model? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Well considering it is a "View" model...I don't think it belongs anywhere other than the UI project.

Comment: But if it's in a specific UI project, it can't be reused between multiple UI projects. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can return list of dynamic object like this -

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Client> clients = clientRepository.GetClients();
    return View(new GridModel(clients.Select(a => new { ClientId = a.ClientId, Name = a.Name, Address = a.Address })));
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that if you create an anonymous/dynamic object you won't have intellisense in your view, since it won't know the type you are using

Comment: Yes, the missing IntelliSense would be inconvenient. Also the same dynamic selection may need to be made in multiple places (at which point one might change them to use a view model class). But this was a solution that I have not used before and will keep in mind. :)